# Quartic with only one singular point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, plane-curves, singularity, quartics

I'm trying to proof that the Curve $C:xz^3-y^4+2y^2z^2-z^4=0$ is irreducible for all fields K, with $char(K)>2$.
I know that the point $(1:0:0)$ is the only singular point and its multiplicity is 3. How can I argument that this curve is irreducible? I guess that I may use Bezeout's Theorem, but I'm not able to write a good argumentation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you set $z = 1$, that will be the graph of a function $x = (y-1)^2$, thus irreducible.